# Как отправлять параметры POST запроса в Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Сегодня только начал изучать Retrofit2 и сразу же столкнулся с проблемами:

- Везде в аннотациях `@POST` и `@GET` нужно прописывать параметры. Но у меня **test.ru/mobile-api.php**. И там формы для ввода данных. Пустой POST отправляю, ошибку выдает
- Мне нужно в ручную расфасовать JSON ответ.
- До сегодняшнего дня я использовал DefaultHttpClient и
  отправлял таким образом:

  ```
  List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
  valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", Application.Login));
  valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit", "20"));
  valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f", "get_all_vacancies"));
  valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", String.valueOf(vacancyPage)));

  HttpResponse httpresponse = HttpUtils.getInstance().post(Application.VACANCY_API, valuePairs);

  final String response = HttpUtils.httpResponse2String(httpresponse);
  if (response != null) {

  }
  ```

Работало и мог проверить `response`.

Но теперь я делаю запрос с помощью `Retrofit2`

**В интерфейсе**

```
@POST("/mobile-api.php")
    Call<List<Model>> getAllVacancies(@Query("login") String login,
                                      @Query("limit") String limit,
                                      @Query("f") String query_name,
                                      @Query("page") String page);
```

**В App классе**

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://test.ru")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

**В MainActivity**

```
App.getApi()
                .getAllVacancies(App.Login, App.Limit, "get_all_vacancies", "1")
                .enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Успех", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                modelList.addAll(response.body());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Произошла ошибка при соединении", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```

Не могу сделать отладку, сразу на `onFailure()` переходит

**Вопрос:** Что я не так делаю?)

Comment: Попробуйте query на field заменить

Comment: Добавил перед `@POST` `@FormUrlEncoded` заработало)) Спасибо.

Comment: А как насчет 2-пункта. Чтобы вручную, в onResponse второй параметр, он уже готовый в List приходит, я хочу в List сам вставлять

Comment: Не очень понял вторую часть. Возможно вам надо заменить тип получаемого объекта на `Responce<ResponceBody>`

Comment: Я имею ввиду, до этого json получал String типом и вручную все как правильно расфасовывал или парсил, ну короче вот. А тут как видите, я получаю уже готовый List

Comment: В моём предыдущем комменте сказано как получить сырой ответ в котором будет инфа в виде строки